# GPRS PPP link, TCP Three way Handshake SYN packet replay Failure Cause

Tags: c, tcp, udp, embedded, gprs

I'm trying TCP on PPP link. UDP over PPP is working fine. But when I start Three Way Handshake with Server before sending TCP data

I DO NOT GET ANY SYN REPLY?

Remote Server IP(Destination IP) has been resolved using DNS Query(using UDP). The Resolved IP is correct as its been tested with online DNS resolver. I am using http ports 80 and/or 8080 as destination port.

Somehow, accidentally by setting URG flag in TCP header while scratching my head, I got reply with ACK-RST flags set in TCP header. This means that TCP checksum is correct as IP checksum is already been tested while using UDP(DNS Query). So, Both the checksums (TCP and IP) are correct.

Is there any additional option require in TCP header to accomplish this or I'm doing it Wrong way. I'm using XC8 compiler on PIC18F Micos.

helping links and suggestion are much appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention all of the TCP/UDP communication is being implement on SIEMENS MC39I GSM Modem.

Comment: Is the remote server on the same subnet as your gateway, by any chance? In this case the gateway needs to be configured to support proxy-ARP.